# OpenLayers map not loading

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

OpenLayers Plugin is installed correctly but when I add a layer I get following message. (CRS is on Pseudo Mercator) Can anyone help me out?

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\s58sj/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py",
>   line 109, in draw
>       self.render(rendererContext)   File "C:\Users\s58sj/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py",
>   line 158, in render
>       for res in self.resolutions(): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
>
> Python version:
>   2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
>
> QGIS version:
>   2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, ebebdf3
>
> Python path:
>   ['C:/PROGRA~2/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing',
>   'C:/PROGRA~2/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python',
>   'C:\Users\s58sj/.qgis2/python',
>   'C:\Users\s58sj/.qgis2/python/plugins',
>   'C:/PROGRA~2/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins',
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\bin\python27.zip',
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\DLLs',
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib',
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win',
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk',
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\bin',
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27',
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL',
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32',
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode',
>   'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISDU~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a bug report rather than a question on StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to load some vector or raster data from the area of your interest first.

Otherwise the plugin will try to load the whole world at zoom level 0.